How does Blazor Server use SingalR in development out of the box?
I notice the interactivity in Blazor Server works out of the box with no additional configuration when working in a local development environment.
It's my understanding that the interactivity depends on having a SignalR server. Is that correct? And if so, where is it configured?
I know there is documentation on how to setup a SignalR server in Azure and configure it in the application, but I'm just wondering how is it working out of the box when you have not done this?

Is that correct? No and yes. The project itself sets up a SignalR hub, so the application itself is the SignalR server. SignalR isn't tied to Azure. The SignalR hub is created inside the .AddServerSideBlazor call its endpoints mapped by  app.MapBlazorHub

Why are you asking this question? I suspect there's another question behind this one. When you create a Blazor Server with dotnet new blazorserver you can run it immediately. You don't have to configure any servers.

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm of the understanding that you HAVE to have a SignalR server to run a public Blazor Server site, and that your choices are either to roll your own (from open source code) or to pay for one in Azure. Are you saying that you can, in fact, deploy a Blazor Server application and it will use its own internal, integrated SignalR Server? If so, where are the specs on performance and such of this compared to paying for one in Azure?

What does Azure have to do with Blazor Server? Have you tried to just create a simple app and run it? As for where are the specs on performance nobody knows what your site does or how much traffic you expect.

@PanagiotisKanavos Of course. I said that I see it works out of the box. It sounds like your answer is "It just works, so don't worry about how it works". Is that right?

No, I'm saying the question is unclear and the comments are even more unclear. It's almost as if you're trying to get a specific answer, perhaps for some sizing document. It doesn't work that way. Nobody can guess what kind of application you're building, how much traffic or how many concurrent users it will have. In Blazor Server every user session keeps data in the server's memory. The longer the users remain active, the longer that memory will be used. You probably need more memory than you need a dedicated SignalR server

@PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, I didn't mean to go on that tangent. I am interested in that, of course, but I didn't mean to confuse the question. I think what's obvious to you is not so obvious to me, and maybe you assume I know more than I do. Does Blazor Server have an integrated SingalR server running within it? The confusing thing for me is all the documentation that seems to assume you will host a SingalR server separately. I haven't seen a single thing talk about there being an integrated SignalR server out of the box, but I've read that it can't work without SignalR.

The interactivity of Blazor Server does rely on the SignalR server.When using interactivity in Blazor Server, the Blazor Server component uses SignalR to maintain a persistent WebSocket connection between the client and the server. Through this connection, the server can push UI updates to the client, and the client can also pass events back to the server. When you create a Blazor Server project, SignalR is automatically included as part of the default configuration of ASP.NET Core. The necessary libraries and middleware are already included in the project, so you don't have to manually configure the SignalR server and can immediately use real-time communication features in your local environment.
Regarding the configuration of SignalR, the SignalR Hubs API enables connected clients to call methods on the server, there by facilitating real-time communication. We can see the method of configuring the relevant Blazor Hub mapping to the path from the extension method of the IEndpointRouteBuilder interface.

ChatGPT didn't understand the question
